# /clang:-1: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) on Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, inheritance

and I have the following error : "/clang:-1: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"

the problem source is this : 
I have a header file  named "Action.h" :

```
#ifndef ACTION_H_
#define ACTION_H_

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "Customer.h"
enum ActionStatus{
    PENDING, COMPLETED, ERROR
};

//Forward declaration
class Restaurant;

class BaseAction{
public:
    BaseAction();
    ActionStatus getStatus() const;
    virtual void act(Restaurant& restaurant)=0;
    virtual std::string toString() const=0;
protected:
    void complete();
    void error(std::string errorMsg);
    std::string getErrorMsg() const;
private:
    std::string errorMsg;
    ActionStatus status;
};
class Order : public BaseAction {
public:
    Order(int id);
    void act(Restaurant &restaurant);
    std::string toString() const;
private:
    const int tableId;
};
#endif
```

and when I try to implement the class baseAction and the derived class Order :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Action.h"


using namespace std;
BaseAction::BaseAction(): errorMsg(""),status(PENDING) {}
ActionStatus BaseAction:: getStatus() const { return status;}
void BaseAction::complete() { status=COMPLETED;}
void BaseAction::error(string errorMsg) { this->errorMsg=errorMsg;}
string BaseAction::getErrorMsg() const { return this->errorMsg;}

Order::Order(int id): tableId(0) { }
```

I get the error. just to clear the error is caused only by this line :

```
 Order::Order(int id): tableId(0) { }
```

*the .cpp file does recognize the header file, so this I reckon not the problem.

thank you very much !

Comment: If you look at the compiler output there should be a more detailed error message

Comment: hey, that's the output :  Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "vtable for Order", referenced from:
      Order::Order(int) in BaseAction.cpp.o
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: The error message give you a hint, you haven't implemented `Order::toString` or `Order::act`. Unrelated but you should add a virtual destructor to `BaseAction`